# How to give a role to a member with custom status on discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am new to discord.py and I was wondering if it's possible to give members a role for a specific custom status and if it's possible to remove it automatically once they remove it too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through all members of the guild. Guild refers to a discord server.
You can get role using role id:

```py
# define guild and role_id variables
role = guild.get_role(role_id)
```

Then you can iterate through all members of the guild using:

```py
#define required_activity
for user in guild.members:
    userHasActivity = false
    for activity in user.activities:
        if isinstance(activity, discord.CustomActivity):
            if str(activity) == required_activity:
                userHasActivity = true
    if userHasActivity:
        await user.add_roles([role])
    else:
        await user.remove_roles(role)
```

If this is used as a command, guild can be obtained using `ctx.guild` which refers to whichever guild the command is run on. You can get guild using server-id using `bot.get_guild`. You can also get all guilds the bot is in using `bot.guilds`. However, the role id will not be the same for different guilds so you'll have to take care to store and set role ids properly.

It can be refactored into a separate `async` function and automated using [discord.ext.tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks).

Note that this can be slow for large servers.

Things to note:

1. Note that this can be slow for large servers.
2. The code above doesn't have error checking whatsoever so you'll need to add that. Use try-catch block to catch errors. It's up to you how to handle errors: log it, ignore it etc.
3. The syntax for `remove_roles` functions is tested on modified version of discord.py 1.7.3 and works but according to the documentation the code should be `await user.remove_roles([role])`. That might be different based on discord.py version.

Comment: Thanks it works but it doesn't seem to remove the role any help with that please?

Comment: There's a difference between asking for help and asking someone to do it all for you and give you the working code. Give it a shot yourself first.

Comment: I tried adding else statement but it didn't work, please if you can help me that would be great please.

Comment: @Turtle_god It would be helpful if you include how you added else statement and how it didn't work. Also see last paragraph: things to note.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def role(ctx):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="role_name")
    # this gets the role (replace the "role name" with the actual role name)
    user = ctx.message.author
    # this gets the user
    if (user.activities == 'status'):
        # this checks if his status is 'status'
        await user.add_roles(role)
        # this grants the user the role
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be probably best, to check it on member update. Every time someone changes their activity, this will run. After knowing the `role` as mentioned how to by Suven Pandey, you use this code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):

    if after.bot == True:
        return

    if before.activities == after.activities:
        return

    # define required_activity
    userHasActivity = False
    for activity in after.activities:
        if isinstance(activity, discord.CustomActivity):
            if str(activity) == required_activity:
                userHasActivity = True
    if userHasActivity:
        await after.add_roles([role])
    else:
        await after.remove_roles([role])
```

It is basically copied from Suven Pandey and just adapted to `on_member_update`. I think this is as close to what you were looking for.