# Discord.py I want a role to be added when someone has a Specific thing in there status

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

my name is Mali my friend Env is trying to make something where it can give people roles if they have his server invite in their bio this is what he has so far:

```
async def status_check(guild):
    while True:
        async for member in guild.fetch_members():
            for s in member.activities:
                if isinstance(s, discord.CustomActivity):
                    if s == "discord.gg/drame":
                        await member.add_roles([discord.Object(960335274745937920)])
        await asyncio.sleep(10)

status_check = True
```

I couldn’t think of anything because I am fairly new to coding

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```py
from discord.utils import get

@bot.event # or @client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
        if after.guild.id == 926498246619189258: # Only attempt to add roles for your server
          if after.activity and after.activity.name.lower() == "discord.gg/drame":
                role_id = 960335274745937920
                role = get(after.guild.roles, id=role_id)
                await after.add_roles(role)
          elif before.activity and before.activity.name.lower() == "discord.gg/drame" and not after.activity:
              role_id = 960335274745937920
              role = get(after.guild.roles, id=role_id)
              await after.remove_roles(role)
```

The above will **only** execute if a member updates their bio/activity.

If you want to check the existing bio/activity of members, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69062936/how-to-give-a-role-to-a-member-with-custom-status-on-discord-py) may help.